# How to split string(IP ADDRESS) in TEXTFILE?

Tags: c#, vb.net

i have textfile with ip address contents like this

```
10.1.11.88
10.1.11.52
10.1.11.35
10.1.11.95
10.1.11.127
10.1.11.91
```

how to `SPLIT` ip address from file?

Comment: `File.ReadLines` isn't enough?

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you are after. Do you need help reading the lines from the file, or separating the components of the IP address itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var ips = File.ReadLines("path")
            .Select(line => IPAddress.Parse(line))
            .ToList();
```

you can use `ips[i].GetAddressBytes()` to split the address.

Answer (score 1):

```
var ipAddresses = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\path.txt");
```

This will create an array with a separate string for each line of your text file.

Comment: i want to split ip and use in another function.

Comment: That gives you a string array. ipAddresses[1] is your first address etc.

Comment: @MeysamSavameri: Please be more specific. When you say "split IP" I understand that to mean you want an array where each IP address is on its own line. If that isn't what you want, how about providing an example of the output you would expect from the sample text file?

Answer (score 1):

I would also validate the string read using ipaddress.tryparse -
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to split an individual IP address into its four (4) components, use `string.Split(char[])`, which will give you a `string[]` containing each portion.

For example:

```
string[] addressSplit = "10.1.11.88".Split('.');
// gives { "10", "1", "11", "88" }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.  Here's the fish:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            System.IO.StreamReader myFileStream;
            string strFileLine;
            String[] arrAddressString;


            myFileStream = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\myTextFile.txt");
            // where "c:\\myTextFile.txt" is the file path and file name.

            while ((strFileLine = myFileStream.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

                arrAddressString = strFileLine.Split('.');

            /*
               Now we have a 0-based string arracy
               p.q.r.s: such that arrAddressString[0] = p, arrAddressString[1] = q,
               arrAddressString[2] = r, arrAddressString[3] = s
            */

            /* here you do whatever you want with the values in the array. */

                // Here, i'm just outputting the elements...

                for (int i = 0; i < arrAddressString.Length; i++)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine(arrAddressString[i]);
                }

                System.Console.ReadKey();
             }
        }
    }
}
```